# Java: Inconsistent NullPointerException

Tags: java, tree, nullpointerexception

I am having trouble with a method in Java thats throwing up an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at FamilyTree$FamilyTreeNode.access$9(FamilyTree.java:5)
at FamilyTree.displayFamilyMember(FamilyTree.java:166)
at FamilyTreeTest.main(FamilyTreeTest.java:28)
```

The method in question is:

```
public void displayFamilyMember(){  
    boolean cascade = false;    
     int memberIdentifier;              
     displayFamily();
     memberIdentifier = Input.getInteger("Input member ID");
     currentNode = ancestor ;
        if (currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier || currentNode.partner.identifier == memberIdentifier){
            cascade = true;
            if(currentNode.partner!= null){
                System.out.println(currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] Partner:  " + currentNode.partner.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.partner.identifier + "]");
                }else{
                    System.out.println(currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] has no partner");
                }
            }           
        if(currentNode.child != null){                              
                 currentNode = currentNode.child;                   
                 if (currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier || cascade == true || currentNode.partner.identifier == memberIdentifier){                      
                     if(currentNode.partner!= null){
                            System.out.println("     " + currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] Partner:  " + currentNode.partner.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.partner.identifier + "]");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("     " + currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] has no partner");
                            }
                     }
        }               

        if (currentNode.sibling!= null){
             while(currentNode.sibling != null){                        
                 currentNode = currentNode.sibling;                 
                    if (currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier || cascade == true || currentNode.partner.identifier  == memberIdentifier){
                     System.out.println("Check for match performed, checking partner !- null");                 
                     if(currentNode.partner!= null){
                            System.out.println("     " + currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] Partner:  " + currentNode.partner.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.partner.identifier + "]");
                            }else{
                                System.out.println("     " + currentNode.Name + " ID[" + currentNode.identifier + "] has no partner");
                            }
                         }
                 }
                 }

        else{
            System.out.println("member not found");
        }


}
```

The line that is throwing the error:

```
 if (currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier || cascade == true || currentNode.partner.identifier == memberIdentifier){
```

Now as a guess, I would say I'm getting this error, because currentNode.partner.identifier, which I'm checking the value of, is null / the currentNode.partner node doesn't exist.

This doesn't prevent the previous two identical checks from functioning correctly, so I'm a bit perplexed as to why this line is any different.

The structure is

```
Alice[2] <--partner-- John[1] 
                     |
                   Ted[3] --sibling--> Eric[4] --sibling--> Joanne[5]
```

---

### EDIT: 
Thanks for the replies, I understand how it works now.

```
if (currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier || currentNode.partner.identifier == memberIdentifier){
```

### On the first Node, this line SHOULD throw the exception, but doesn't because the first condition is met and the others don't get checked. Referencing currentNode.partner.identifier while currentNode.partner = Null was the problem.

Comment: Have you gone through in debugger to check that that is the case?

Comment: Your assumptions must be incorrect. Let's test them: What happens if you check the values of these fields *just before* the offending line? Also a word of advice: please try to format your code nicely when posting here as if it's hard to read such as if you have very long lines, it's hard for us to understand.

Comment: Plus if at all possible include a full (but as short as possible) compilable code that exibits the problem

Comment: Since you are using ORs once a true condition is found it will stop checking the rest of the conditions

Comment: The method searches through the structure in the OP, for an identifier supplied by the user, then matches it to a node and displays that node. Would using OR matter, since only the node or it's partner can match the identifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking at your code, the only reason I'd expect that specific line to throw a null reference error was if `currentNode.partner` was null.

The reason why it's different every time, is because you keep changing `currentNode` like so

```
currentNode = currentNode.sibling;
```

---

Additionally, if your If condition looks like `if (A || B)` than it will always be true when `A` is true regardless of what `B` is, so It won't check `B` when `A` is true.

because of this behavior and it's inverse with `&&`, you might see conditions that look like

```
if(myObj != null && myObj.value == otherVal)
```

---

Your previous line might never have executed

`currentNode.partner.identifier == memberIdentifier`

if `currentNode.identifier == memberIdentifier` or `cascade` was true

---

Because of this, Even if the exact same line executed when `currentNode.partner` was not null, that might not be the case after you change `currentNode`

---

If I were you, I'd find a good java debugger, and put a breakpoint before where the error occurs.

Comment: CurrentNode is the node I use to move through the structure, and display the contents of the node it is currently on. What I mean't by in consistent was, if the currentNode is on the first Node, and it has no partner, it will throw no error. If it is on the second node (the child node), it will throw no error. If it is on a sibling node, it will throw an error, all using the same test.

Ill find a debugger, thanks for the advice :)

Comment: @Shuma both the IDEs elipse and netbeans come with debuggers built in.

Comment: @Shuma If it were `currentNode.identifier` that was null than your code wouldn't be throwing exceptions on that line.  it's `currentNode.partner` which would be null

Comment: Just turned it on there, I  can't believe I've not been using it

Comment: With a bit more testing i've narrowed it down to referencing "currentNode.partner.Identifier" when "currentNode.partner" = null.

Edit: I think I see your point with the OR's now, it would explai why no error is thrown on the parent and child nodes, thanks!